# PHP cURL 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size' for large data sets

Tags: php, memory-leaks, curl, large-data-volumes

I know about the option to set the internal memory

```
ini_set("memory_limit","30M");
```

But I wanted to know if there is a better approach for querying data?

I have a WHILE LOOP that checks to see if I need to query for another 1000 records.
using the offset as the starting record number and the limit as the returned records, I search for all records matching my data request. I hit about 100K in records before I get the error.

Now during testing I found that I get the 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size...' error. I've read by setting the above ini_set() to allow for the increase in memory but I wanted to know if I could just code it better?

Each time I execute the code below in the WHILE LOOP, the memory usage grows very large. Even if I unset($curl). I think it could be reduced if I could unset the $result and $curl variables after I have parsed out the results before the next cURL query.

```
function getRequest($url,$user,$pwd) {

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pwd");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $httpResponseCode = (int)curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    switch ($httpResponseCode) {
        case 500:
            // Send problem email
            break;
        case 200:
            // GET was good
            break;
        default:
            // Send problem email
            break;
    }    
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

WHILE LOOP (Slim version)

```
while($queryFlag) { // $queryFlag is TRUE

        // Check if we have more records to query, if not set $queryFlag to FALSE

        // Build cURL URL

        echo "Before Call Memory Usage: ".memory_get_usage()."\n";
        $resultXML  = getRequest($query,$user,$pass);
        echo "After Call Memory Usage: ".memory_get_usage()."\n";

        $results        = new ParseXMLConfig((string)$resultXML); // This is basically a class for $this->xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

        // Loop through results and keep what  I'm looking for
        foreach($results as $resultsKey => $resultsData) {
            if(preg_match('|^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$|i', $resultsData)) {
                $resultsArr["$resultsData"] = $resultsData;
            }
        }

    }
```

Some memory numbers

- Before Call Memory Usage: 1819736
- After Call Memory Usage: 2285344
- keep data I need
- dump data I don't need
- Next LOOP Iteration
- Before Call Memory Usage: 2084128
- After Call Memory Usage: 2574952

Comment: Can you show us the while loop as well, please?

Comment: Do you have xdebug installed? It might give you some useful info.

Comment: the WHILE LOOP is fine, I do memory_get_usage() before the cURL and after the cURL call and this is where the memory gets crazy large. The while loop just checks to see if we need to query again. if records are greater then the last 1000 returned. Parses out the return and pushes that wanted data into an array. I've checked to see if the array was the issue but it's very very small, only a could hundred records with minimal data in each record.

Comment: I don't have xDebug installed, it's not my server :(

Comment: Your function looks fine.   Something in the loop code is chewing up memory.  Post the loop code.

Comment: added WHILE LOOP code. I've also tried to unset about everything I can and it's the cURL getRequest that's adding the memory overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settled for:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","30M");
```

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you are using incorrect *key* for `$resultsArr`. You are using same string as both key and value.

Try changing

```
$resultsArr["$resultsData"] = $resultsData
```

to

```
$resultsArr[$resultsKey] = $resultsData
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to OP's question, "can I just code better?".  You're asking the right question!  Good on ya.

I had an issue similar to this, where I had a loop and something in the loop was chewing up memory.  What I discovered was that, I think, because I was saving the data I wanted to 'keep' to an object (stdClass), that's what was slowing things down.  I changed it so instead of something like:

```
$payloadObject->someNewAttribute = $data_i_want_to_keep;
```

I used an indexed array:

```
$payload_array[] = $data_i_want_to_keep;
```

That worked out for me.

I saw a test somewhere (and tried it out myself and found my results in agreement with what I saw) for getting / setting on a `stdClass` object, an associative array, and an indexed array.  I forget if it was speed or memory, but setting on `stdClass` uses more memory / is slower than setting an associative array key / value, which is slower / uses more memory than just adding a new indexed array item.  I.e.:

```
//  slowest / most memory intensive
$some_stdClass_object->some_new_attribute = $data_I_want_to_keep;

//  slower / still memory intensive
$some_array["some_new_key"] = $data_I_want_to_keep;

//  optimal / fastest
$some_array[] = $data_I_want_to_keep;
```

I noticed this line, after looking your code over again (comment moved for readability):

```
// This is basically a class for $this->xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$results        = new ParseXMLConfig((string)$resultXML);
```

It looks like you're setting the xml to an attribute on a class (whatever class `$this` is).  That could very well be what's eating your memory.  Maybe look at that function (ParseXMLConfig) and see if you can change saving that data to the object, to saving it in maybe an indexed array or an associative array if you need.